# Placeholder in loop body and executing procedure in Toad with no paramter

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have following two separate short questions.

**1.)** I was writing procedure in PL/SQL and came across a question of whether there is any placeholder for loop body in PL/SQL similar to python. For instance,

```py
if age>11
   pass   --Pass can placed in python code and program will run. Does anything like PASS exist in PL/SQL oracle?
elif
   pass
--
```

I tried to look into oracle docs but could not find anything relevant.

**2).** How I can execute procedures, with no parameter, inside package in Toad 
 (v-12.6.0.53). I tried executing package by right-clicking in package but it doesn't give me the option of running procedure until and unless I don't add parameters in it.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) The Statement NULL; is a placeholder statement will meet the requirements for a block to have a statement, but do nothing:

```
if age>11 then
   null;
elsif age < 1 then
   null;
else ...
```

2.) Don't have TOAD anymore, but in a SQL Editor window you can always execute a procedure directly:

```
BEGIN
   mypackage.myproc();
end;
```

IF there is a way to do it easier from the Schema Browser... maybe someone else can shed light on that

Comment: Thanks! Looks like Toad doesn't support it via schema for procs with no parameters. Posted here to confirm if anyone know a way to run procs, with no params, via schema browser.

Comment: Sachin, can you expand upon your Schema Browser problem? I have a package containing a procedure that has no parameters. I rt-click, choose Execute Package, select my procedure and click OK. The Arguments grid is empty because the proc has no params, this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

A package procedure without parameters does not require the parentheses:

```
create or replace package  mypackage is
    procedure myproc;
end;     
create or replace package  body mypackage is
    procedure myproc 
    is
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line('In mypackage.myproc');
    end ; 
end ;     

-- test  
begin 
    mypackage.myproc; 
end;
```